# Ring homomorphisms in k-algebras.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I have this question to complete:

Define $a:Fun(Y,k)→Fun(X,k)$  by $a(g)=g∘f$
Give an example of an integral domain $k$, finite sets $X,Y$ and a ring homomorphism $Fun(Y,k)$ to $Fun(X,k)$ that is not of the form $f∗$ for any $f:X→Y$. I have started by taking $X=Y=\{pt\}$ and $k=\mathbb{C}$.
Do I need just a non identity homomorphism from $Fun(Y,k)$ to $Fun(X,k)$?

Comment: Presumably, the ring structure on $Fun(Y,k)$ is the induced one from $k$; that is, $(f+g)(x)=f(x)+g(x)$ and $(fg)(x)=f(x)g(x)$. So a ring homomorphism $\phi:Fun(Y,k)\rightarrow Fin(X,k)$ would be something that satisfies $(\phi(f+g))(x)=\phi(f)(x)+\phi(g)(x)$ and $\phi(fg)(x)=\phi(f)(x)\phi(g)(x)$ for all $x\in X$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elaborating on the hint: if $X=Y=\{pt\}$, the set with one point, then $Fun(X,k)=Fun(Y,k)=k$ identically (since every function $f$ can be identified with its unique image $f(pt)\in k$). Since the only function $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is the identity $pt\mapsto pt$, you just need to produce a non-identity homomorphism $\phi:k\rightarrow k$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, you've really cleared this up for me! I didn't first understand the ring structure being induced from $k$. I have taken the non- identity homomorphism to be the complex conjugation.

Comment: That would be a good choice!

Comment: Okay, I think I've completed the proof now :) thanks again for your help!
I am very new to category theory and anything associated with it. It's hard to understand what a morphism of morphisms is at first!