# $k$-algebra morphism from Fun$(Y,k)$ to Fun$(X,k)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, category-theory

Let $X,Y$ be finite sets, $k$ an integral domain. Then Fun$(X,k)$ is the set of functions of $X$ to $k$.

I am trying to prove that every $k$-algebra morphism from Fun$(Y,k)$ to Fun$(X,k)$ is of the form $f^*$, where $f^*$: Fun$(Y,k)\rightarrow $Fun$(X,k)$ such that $f^*(g)=g \circ f$ for some function $f:X\rightarrow Y$.

I have proved that $f^*$ is itself a morphism of k-algebras but am struggling to find a function $f$ that allows me to write any $k$-algebra morphism in the form $f^*$. Any help of hints would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It would be helpful if you would define your terms. Is Fun functions? homomorphisms? Are your $k$-algebras assumed to be commutative? unital?

Comment: What are $X$ and $Y?$

Comment: Apologies. For a finite sets $X$, $Y$ and integral domain $k$, Fun$(X,k)$ is the set of functions of $X$ to $k$.

Comment: Related https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2500287/ring-homomorphisms-in-k-algebras. That is about ring homomorphisms, not $k$-algebra homomorphisms, so it does not actually give a counterexample to this question (which I should have noticed, thanks @JeremyRickard for pointing out my mistake). But it might still be relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Focus on the idempotent elements of these algebras: that is, elements $x$ such that $x^2=x$.  Note that if $x$ is idempotent and $\varphi$ is a homomorphism, then $\varphi(x)$ is idempotent.  Can you describe all the the idempotent elements of $\operatorname{Fun}(X,k)$?  Can you describe what $f^*$ does to the idempotent elements, and prove that any homomorphism must do something similar?

Comment: I think I've carried this hint to its logical conclusion, but just to be clear, does this prove the claim in the question, or show why the statement is incorrect, as other commenters have claimed?

Comment: The statement is correct.  (It is not correct if you only had a ring homomorphism rather than a $k$-algebra homomorphism.)

Comment: I am having trouble seeing what $f$ gives the $0$ homomorphism of $k$-algebras by precomposition. Using the hint, precomposition by $f$ turns into preimage map on subsets of the domains $X,Y$ when applied to idempotents. The map which sends all of $Y$ to the empty set is not the preimage map of any function $X\to Y$.

Comment: There is no "$0$-homomorphism".  We're talking about unital algebras.

Comment: Yes, of course. Thanks for explaining.